# Discrepancy between df and du

Tags: disk-usage, df, du

I'm tracking down disk usage, and I am getting different results from `df` and `du`.

When I installed Ubuntu, I ticked the box to encrypt my home directory, so my `df -h` outputs the following mounts (among others, of course):

```bsh
/dev/sda1                86G   81G  1.4G  99% /
# ...
/home/myusername/.Private   86G   81G  1.4G  99% /home/myusername
```

However, when I run `du`, I don't see anywhere near 80 GB:

```bsh
du -h -d0 /home/myusername
# => 45G    /home/myusername
du -h -d0 /home/myusername/.Private
# => 45G    /home/myusername/.Private
```

The disk in fact appears to be nearly full (80+ GB as opposed to 45 GB). When I try to install a GB worth of game on Steam, it tells me that the disk is full.

**Why the discrepancy? What can I do to find what files are taking up the ~40 GB that are unaccounted for in my `du` output?** I've already tried the solution given [here](https://serverfault.com/a/275208/149693) (checking for files under the mount point), and there are only a few symlinks, no culprits.

Comment: There are *several* answers to the question you linked but you only indicated that you tried one of them. This question has also been asked at least a dozen times.  This seems to be another duplicate.  Can you read through all of the answers?  Know that file size / free space is almost always an *estimate*, since it would be horribly resource intensive to constantly update this information.  Different tools use different methods to estimate this data.

Comment: @NMath Thanks for your feedback. I have read the other answers. Unfortunately, I spotted only one other answer that wasn't trivially obvious (check for deleted files using `lsof`), and it likewise did not account for significant disk usage in my case. The remaining answers were to check inode usage, use `ls`, reboot, look for zombie processes.